# Android compose snackbar showing again on config changes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to display a snackbar once, on android compose, but as soon as I change the screen rotation, the snackbar shows again, i took this example from official android documentation and it is doing the same thing:

```
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(
    state: Boolean = true,
    scaffoldState: ScaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
) {
    // If the UI state contains an error, show snackbar
    if (state) {

        // `LaunchedEffect` will cancel and re-launch if
        // `scaffoldState.snackbarHostState` changes
        LaunchedEffect(scaffoldState.snackbarHostState) {
            // Show snackbar using a coroutine, when the coroutine is cancelled the
            // snackbar will automatically dismiss. This coroutine will cancel whenever
            // `state.hasError` is false, and only start when `state.hasError` is true
            // (due to the above if-check), or if `scaffoldState.snackbarHostState` changes.
            scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                message = "Error message",
                actionLabel = "Retry message"
            )
        }
    }

    Scaffold(scaffoldState = scaffoldState) {
    }
}
```

My question is: How do you display a snackbar once with a side effect even if the rotation changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, you can save the state to a local variable using [`rememberSaveable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/saveable/package-summary#rememberSaveable(kotlin.Array,androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.Saver,kotlin.String,kotlin.Function0)) and set it to `false` when the snackbar disappears.

```
var localState by rememberSaveable(state) { mutableStateOf(state) }
// If the UI state contains an error, show snackbar
if (localState) {

    // `LaunchedEffect` will cancel and re-launch if
    // `scaffoldState.snackbarHostState` changes
    LaunchedEffect(scaffoldState.snackbarHostState) {
        // Show snackbar using a coroutine, when the coroutine is cancelled the
        // snackbar will automatically dismiss. This coroutine will cancel whenever
        // `state.hasError` is false, and only start when `state.hasError` is true
        // (due to the above if-check), or if `scaffoldState.snackbarHostState` changes.
        scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
            message = "Error message",
            actionLabel = "Retry message"
        )
        localState = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Im actually doing something like this in my app, in my case im telling the view model that the snackbar was dismissed this way im able to set to null the snackbar message, however, i think that your local state aproach is cleaner.

Comment: @Philip Dukhov does it comply with Unidirectional Data Flow architecture?